# How to "push_back" objects using armadillo?

Tags: c++, armadillo

How to create a dynamic-size field object in armadillo such that you can later on `push_back` things into it?

I tried the `<<` operator, but the pre-created field object won't be enlarged.

Comment: Trying is usually not a good idea. Most major libraries are well documented. It's not clear what you are asking, please post a [mre] and any errors you get.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28247490/push-back-append-or-appending-a-vector-with-a-loop-in-c-armadillo

Comment: Armadillo containers are useful for linear algebra and math manipulation and they are not *supposed* to be used like this. If you just want to append elements a `std::vector` would be more appropriated. If you need to use armadillo for the math and linear algebra then it is probably better if you break the logic into two steps, one to just find the size and another to fill the elements.

Comment: You can use `resize` to change the size while keeping elements and preserving layout,
http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#resize_member

Comment: I'm agree with @darcamo. If I really need to use a push_back, I use std::vector and at the end, I call arma::conv_to<arma::vec>. It's faster than resizing the vector in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I know Armadillo has "reshape", "reserve" capability, it can't push_back thing like std:: vector.